# BigQuery history of jobs submitted through Python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am submitting BigQuery queries using the Python API, but when I go to bigquery.cloud.google.com and in the query history, I am not able to find queries that I have submitted through the API. In my use-case I am trying to keep track of amount of data that is being processed in each query and also total amount of data processed in the whole of my BigQuery account. Any information on how to find the above would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using same account while submitting API and when go to BQ UI?

Comment: I have created a service account in my Project and am using the service key json file to create the client and send API requests. Thank you

Comment: that's the point! so when you check BQ UI (bigquery.cloud.google.com) you most likely use your personal account - right?

Comment: Yes, I use my personal account. Though I have created my service account through a project my personal gmail, I am not sure to access BigQuery through my service account.

Comment: in bq ui you can only see jobs/query issued by the same account that you logged into it (ui) with. hope this answers your question of why you do not see those jobs

Comment: Thank you, any thoughts on how to access the jobs issued by my service account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BQ UI you can only see jobs that were issued by the account that you logged with. That is why you do not see jobs issued by service account when you logged with you personal account

To get jobs issued by your service account - you can use [Jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) API

> Lists all jobs that you started in the specified project. Job information is available for a six month period after creation. The job list is sorted in reverse chronological order, by job creation time. Requires the Can View project role, or the Is Owner project role if you set the allUsers property.

Comment: Just to add to Mikhail's answer, you can conveniently use the CLI tool (which of course just wraps the API) - `bq ls -j --all`

Comment: I have used bqclient.list_jobs() in Python API to list all the jobs that I have submitted through the Service Account. QueryJob has 3 properties related to bytes: total_bytes_billed, maximum_bytes_billed and total_bytes_processed. What would be the difference between these 3, and which property would give an accurate estimate of my usage. Thanks

Comment: @PramodSripada - total_bytes_billed